# Passing multiple HTTP API URL in PHP

Tags: php, matomo

Am needing to call two or more `HTTP API` to `GET` `META` from Piwik Analytics. Unfortunately, their method of `method=API.getBulkRequest` will not work for a PHP call, and only for JSON and XML - both of which do not work in this request.

Is it possible to combine

```
https://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=Actions.get&idSite=7&period=month&date=last3&format=xml&token_auth=anonymous
```

and

```
https://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.get&idSite=7&period=month&date=last3&format=xml&token_auth=anonymous
```

Using this method of calling `API`

```
$url = "https://demo.piwik.org/";
$url .= "?module=API&method=Actions.get";
$url .= "&idSite=7&period=month&date=last3";
$url .= "&format=php&filter_sort_order=desc";
$url .= "&token_auth=anonymous";
```

so I can `GET` the data using

```
foreach ($content as $dates => $row) {
    $visits = @$row['nb_pageviews'] ?: 0;
    $unique = @$row['nb_uniq_pageviews'] ?: 0;
    $actions = @$row['nb_outlinks'] ?: 0;
    $bounce = @$row['bounce_count'] ?: 0;
    $bounce_rate = @$row['bounce_rate'] ?: 0;
    $time = @$row['avg_time_on_site'] ?: 0;
```

Thank you for your help and Merry Xmas tomorrow

UPDATE OF FULL CODE IN `.PHP` file

```
<?php
            $url = "https://demo.piwik.org/";
            $url .= "?module=API&method=Actions.get";
            $url .= "&idSite=7&period=month&date=last3";
            $url .= "&format=php&filter_sort_order=desc";
            $url .= "&token_auth=anonymous";

            $fetched = file_get_contents($url);
            $content = unserialize($fetched);
            krsort($content);

            // case error
            if (!$content) {
                print("<tr><td class='month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell'></td><td class='stat number text-center'>Error, analytics not available at the moment.</td></tr>");
            }

            foreach ($content as $dates => $row) {
                $visits = @$row['nb_pageviews'] ?: 0;
                $unique = @$row['nb_uniq_pageviews'] ?: 0;
                $actions = @$row['nb_outlinks'] ?: 0;
                $bounce = @$row['bounce_count'] ?: 0;
                $bounce_rate = @$row['bounce_rate'] ?: 0;
                $time = @$row['avg_time_on_site'] ?: 0;

                $date = $dates;
                $action_percent = get_percentage($visits,$actions);
                $unique_percent = get_percentage($visits,$unique);

                print("<tr>");
                print("<td class='month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell'>" .date('F Y',strtotime($date)). "</td>");
                print("<td class='stat number text-center'>$visits</td>");
                print("<td class='stat number text-center'>$unique ($unique_percent%)</td>");
                print("<td class='stat number text-center'>$actions ($action_percent%)</td>");
                print("<td class='stat number text-center'>$bounce ($bounce_rate)</td>");
                print("<td class='stat number text-center'>$time</td>");
                print("</tr>");
            }?>
```

Comment: And why are two separate calls not possible?

Comment: why will their `API.getBulkRequest` not work in PHP?

Comment: They require the format to be either JSON or XML.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware. I tried an additional `$url =` yet it just stopped all data from being retrieved.

Comment: `"To send a bulk tracking request, an HTTP POST must be made with a JSON object to the Piwik tracking endpoint."` ? that is from their api documentation. What is the problem sending that type of request data - json is nothing special

Comment: Well, ask a question about that, you cannot combine two URL calls into one, you have to make two separate calls. PHP has no problem with this. If you need bulk results a bulk call will be better.

Comment: @RamRaider. I am not using JS to display the data and only calling the Piwik HTTP API in PHP. Otherwise, JSON would be fine to work with.

Comment: OK - I see the limitation now you have updated your code ~ it was unclear how you retrieving the data before. You can add a `context` argument to `file_get_contents` that would allow you to send the request via POST with additional parameters

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sorry, agreed. However as mentioned in above, JSON or XML is not possible here. Was perhaps hoping for a solution that could be used within current call. I think the best solution is to use JS to retrieve the Bulk Request and pass to PHP.

Comment: @RamRaider that is great, I'll give it a go now. Cheers.

Comment: The easiest method, IMO, would be to change from using `file_get_contents` ( which is quite limiting and the context argument is hard to construct properly ) and start using curl.

Comment: Thank you @RamRaider. I had just realised that and with some Googling I came across this article http://bytes.schibsted.com/php-perform-requests-in-parallel/. It seems a little over my head but I'll try working through it. If you wanted to add your suggestions to an answer so I can accept. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `getBulkRequest` ( details of which I could not find on their website ) or even the other API calls you might find that using curl is easier as you can quickly tailor the request by changing a few options passed to the curl function below and constructing a different `$params` payload.

```
function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL ){
    /*
        Download a copy of cacert.pem from
        https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

        and then edit below as appropriate
    */
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';

    /* for advanced debugging info */
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');


    $res=array(
        'response'  =>  NULL,
        'info'      =>  array( 'http_code' => 100 ),
        'headers'   =>  NULL,
        'errors'    =>  NULL
    );
    if( is_null( $url ) ) return (object)$res;

    session_write_close();

    /* Initialise curl request object */
    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    }

    /* Define standard options */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

    /* advanced debugging info */
    curl_setopt( $curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true );
    curl_setopt( $curl,CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,true );
    curl_setopt( $curl,CURLOPT_STDERR,$vbh );

    /* Assign runtime parameters as options */
    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }

    /* Execute the request and store responses */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );

    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );

    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}

/*
The original url
----------------
$url = "https://demo.piwik.org/";
$url .= "?module=API&method=Actions.get";
$url .= "&idSite=7&period=month&date=last3";
$url .= "&format=php&filter_sort_order=desc";
$url .= "&token_auth=anonymous";
*/

$url='https://demo.piwik.org/';

/* original url as array of parameters to POST */
$params=array(
    'module'            =>  'API',
    'method'            =>  'Actions.get',
    'idSite'            =>  7,
    'period'            =>  'month',
    'date'              =>  'last3',
    'format'            =>  'php',
    'filter_sort_order' =>  'desc',
    'token_auth'        =>  'anonymous'

);
/* Set the options for POSTing the data */
$options=array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>  http_build_query( $params ),
    CURLOPT_POST        =>  true
);
/* Make the request */
$result = curl( $url, $options );

/* If the response status code is 200 (OK) do stuff with data */
if( $result->info->http_code==200 ){
    $data=unserialize( $result->response );
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data,true),'</pre>';
} else {
    /* panic */
    echo "Error: {$result->info->http_code}";
}
```

The above will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [2017-10] => Array
        (
            [nb_pageviews] => 37849
            [nb_uniq_pageviews] => 30775
            [nb_downloads] => 54
            [nb_uniq_downloads] => 50
            [nb_outlinks] => 1911
            [nb_uniq_outlinks] => 1808
            [nb_searches] => 1452
            [nb_keywords] => 925
            [avg_time_generation] => 0.672
        )

    [2017-11] => Array
        (
            [nb_pageviews] => 36409
            [nb_uniq_pageviews] => 29518
            [nb_downloads] => 50
            [nb_uniq_downloads] => 48
            [nb_outlinks] => 1841
            [nb_uniq_outlinks] => 1724
            [nb_searches] => 1238
            [nb_keywords] => 775
            [avg_time_generation] => 0.672
        )

    [2017-12] => Array
        (
            [nb_pageviews] => 28945
            [nb_uniq_pageviews] => 21623
            [nb_downloads] => 34
            [nb_uniq_downloads] => 28
            [nb_outlinks] => 1343
            [nb_uniq_outlinks] => 1280
            [nb_searches] => 819
            [nb_keywords] => 507
            [avg_time_generation] => 0.832
        )

)
```

To use the `getBulkRequest` feature of the api - something along these lines should get you started.

```
$params=array(
    'module'            =>  'API',
    'method'            =>  'API.getBulkRequest',
    'format'            =>  'json',
    'token_auth'        =>  'anonymous'
);
$urls=array(
    array( 'method' => 'VisitsSummary.get', 'idSite' => 7, 'date' => 'last3', 'period' => 'month' ),
    array( 'method' => 'VisitsSummary.get', 'idSite' => 7, 'date' => 'september', 'period' => 'day' )
);              
$tmp=array();
foreach( $urls as $index => $site ) $tmp[]='urls['.$index.']='.urlencode( http_build_query( $site ) );


/* Set the options for POSTing the data */
$options=array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>  http_build_query( $params ) . '&' . implode('&',$tmp),
    CURLOPT_POST        =>  true
);


/* Make the request */
$result = curl( $url, $options );

/* If the response status code is 200 (OK) do stuff with data */
if( $result->info->http_code==200 ){
    $data=json_decode( $result->response );
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data,true),'</pre>';
} else {
    /* panic */
    echo "Error: {$result->info->http_code}";
}
```

The above ( for `getBulkRequests` ) will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [2017-10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nb_uniq_visitors] => 16911
                    [nb_users] => 0
                    [nb_visits] => 21425
                    [nb_actions] => 41266
                    [nb_visits_converted] => 1
                    [bounce_count] => 14400
                    [sum_visit_length] => 2776649
                    [max_actions] => 59
                    [bounce_rate] => 67%
                    [nb_actions_per_visit] => 1.9
                    [avg_time_on_site] => 130
                )

            [2017-11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nb_uniq_visitors] => 16108
                    [nb_users] => 0
                    [nb_visits] => 20523
                    [nb_actions] => 39538
                    [nb_visits_converted] => 2
                    [bounce_count] => 13900
                    [sum_visit_length] => 2639042
                    [max_actions] => 171
                    [bounce_rate] => 68%
                    [nb_actions_per_visit] => 1.9
                    [avg_time_on_site] => 129
                )

            [2017-12] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nb_uniq_visitors] => 12156
                    [nb_users] => 0
                    [nb_visits] => 15199
                    [nb_actions] => 31149
                    [nb_visits_converted] => 4
                    [bounce_count] => 10231
                    [sum_visit_length] => 2069782
                    [max_actions] => 830
                    [bounce_rate] => 67%
                    [nb_actions_per_visit] => 2
                    [avg_time_on_site] => 136
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nb_uniq_visitors] => 311
            [nb_users] => 0
            [nb_visits] => 347
            [nb_actions] => 592
            [nb_visits_converted] => 2
            [bounce_count] => 229
            [sum_visit_length] => 33879
            [max_actions] => 12
            [bounce_rate] => 66%
            [nb_actions_per_visit] => 1.7
            [avg_time_on_site] => 98
        )

)
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure the POST for bulkRequests

Comment: Yes, I spent a rather long time reading the documentation and thought that their example of  `curl -i -X POST -d 'module=API&method=API.getBulkRequest&format=json&urls[0]=method%3dVisitsSummary.get%26idSite%3d3%26date%3d2012-03-06%26period%3dday&urls[1]=method%3dVisitorInterest.getNumberOfVisitsPerVisitDuration%26idSite%3d3%26date%3d2012-03-06%26period%3dday' https://demo.piwik.org/index.php` would work. Yet, I cannot get to do so.

Comment: I'd not heard of `piwik` before now - I'm impressed so far and will, in the future, implement this for myself I think - Thanks Darren!

Comment: Wow. This is great and I accepted it as the correct answer. However, did you get the output as posted above? I currently get `Error:0`. With zero errors in the console or logs. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, Piwik is great. I find it a little slow but that may be the way I have implemented. We'll tidy that later. Using it firstly to host our own Analytics but also, Heatmaps and Screen Recordings are great. Along with the ability to create accounts programmatically with new user accounts.

Comment: I too initially was getting that error - checked the error log and saw messages about `unserialize(): Error at offset 0 ` so looked at the data returned and it is json so used `json_decode` rather than `unserialize` and then got the response as shown

Comment: Could it have anything to do with `$cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';`? I know a little about this but never used it. Is this required on the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161890/discussion-between-ramraider-and-darren).

Answer (score 0):

Moin,
can' t you you use the bulk request feature of the Piwik API:
See https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api (Advanced Users: Send multiple API Requests at once) ?

Also, i would recommend to use a HTTP client library such as https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle which has a set of very nice features to facilitate server side HTTP calls (e.g. sync and async mode)

Comment: Thank you, Guzzle does look like a great library. Found it 20 minutes ago and look forward to delving further. Will give RamRaider answer a go first. Thank you again for your time.